# Component instance namespace/id that can be used in templates

Tags: angular

I understand how to use **ElementRef** and that one should avoid setting element ids, but there are still situations where you want to set an element's id attribute.

For example, with inputs and labels (cannot nest because of 3rd party CSS):

```
<input [attr.id]="'myinput'+instanceId" />
<label = [attr.for]="'myinput'+instanceId">My Label</label>
```

I've just been incrementing a number like this for simplicity:

```
let numInstances = 0;

@Component({

})
export class MyComponent {

  private instanceId: number;

  constructor(){
    this.instanceId = numInstances++;
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a Component Instance namespace I can use in templates instead. Something like this? Angular2 would replace # with unique string for component instance.

```
<input [attr.id]="#myinput" />
<label = [attr.for]="#myinput">My Label</label>
```

If this doesn't exist, do you think I should make a feature request to the Angular2 team?

Comment: are you looking for component name ??? do you want to get component name from code?

Comment: @micronyks No, an identifier unique to a Component instance. I don't care what it looks like as long as the characters are valid for an HTML id attribute.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @AravindanVe No, though I just was searching angular.io and found: [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html)  Haven't looked at it yet, but maybe the hostId is in one of those fields? Though it's not part of the public API. In general I rarely need this, but I still think it would be nice if Angular provided it somehow.

Answer (score 5):

After reading some discussions online I decided to use lodash method proposed in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5145#issuecomment-256354115

It works for me, hope it helps someone else!